# usage of validate request and enable event validation in page tag of aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [enableEventValidation and validateRequest difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120377/enableeventvalidation-and-validaterequest-difference)

can someone explain correctly the need of

```
 validateRequest="false" 
  enableEventValidation="false"
```

in page tag

Comment: See this link for more details


 http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation

Answer (score 2):

### **For  enableEventValidation="false"**

Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.enableeventvalidation.aspx).

**EDIT**: For security reasons, it's probably best to leave it set to true wherever you can.

I would therefore recommend that you set it to false only on the individual AJAX pages where it causes problems, while leaving it true in web.config.

### For validateRequest="false"

The "benefit" is that you have more control over the input validation. If `ValidateRequest = true` and the input has invalid characters then an ugly error page is showed to the user.

Although a little old, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx) you have a MSDN post about "Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET"

Comment: Give comment if it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are asking for a valid scenario where I would set `validateRequest="false"` and/or `enableEventValidation="false"`.

`enableEventValidation="false"` is typically required when you use java-script to manipulate server control generated html. For example, if server side drop-down control was bound to have three values say "A","B","C" then those are only values expected when post-back happens. But if you are doing client-side manipulation and hence introduce extra value "D" and select it then ASp.NET will raise event validation error. So we have to suppress it. Particularly, changing the drop-down value (without post-back) can be quite common - populating cities based on state selection etc

`validateRequest="false"` is needed when you want to allow user to enter character sequences those are deemed dangerous - e.g. `<script>bla bla...</script>` will raise request validation error but if you are developing a developer forum/QA site such as SO that allows to post the code then request validation has to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The `ValidateRequest` setting examines user input for potentially harmful information. For example, if `ValidateRequest` is set to true and you enter some markup into an TextBox, the request validation will fail and the page will error out.

The `EnableEventValidation` setting determines whether postback and callback events should validate that a control event originated from the user interface that was rendered by the control. This is usually encountered when server-side events are triggered by the user through JavaScript, like calling the `__doPostBack` function for example.